# Continuously swap images without any hover or other triggers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to write code that works WITHOUT "on hover" or any other triggers. This is just an example with the hover event. I just want the images to continuously appear one by one without any trigger. I believe it is very possible, but not sure how to actually do it. I've written the code I've right now. Any help would be great!

```js
var western = ["https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logos-brands-in-colors/436/Google_Pay_GPay_Logo-512.png", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Apple_Pay_logo.svg/2560px-Apple_Pay_logo.svg.png", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/40/Klarna_Payment_Badge.svg/2560px-Klarna_Payment_Badge.svg.png"];

function getRandomWesternImage() {
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * western.length);
  return western[index];
}

$("#western-wrapper").hover(
  function() {
    var image = getRandomWesternImage();
    $("#western").attr("src", image);
    console.log(image);

    for (var i = 0; i < western.length; i++) {
      // create the image element
      var imageElement = document.createElement('img');
      imageElement.setAttribute('src', western[i]);
    }
  });

$("#western-wrapper").mouseout(function() {
  $("#western").attr("src", "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logos-brands-in-colors/436/Google_Pay_GPay_Logo-512.png");
  console.log(image);
});
```

```css
.img2 {
  max-width: 110px;
  margin-bottom: 0.1px;
}
```

```html
<span id="western-wrapper">
       <img id="western" class="img2" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logos-brands-in-colors/436/Google_Pay_GPay_Logo-512.png" />
</span>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.11.4/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're loading both TweenMax and jQuery twice, and you forgot to tag jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the image every 5 seconds, try this:

```js
let western = ["https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logos-brands-in-colors/436/Google_Pay_GPay_Logo-512.png", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Apple_Pay_logo.svg/2560px-Apple_Pay_logo.svg.png", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/40/Klarna_Payment_Badge.svg/2560px-Klarna_Payment_Badge.svg.png"];

function getRandomWesternImage() {
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * western.length);
  return western[index];
}

let imageTimer;

function updateImage() {
    var image = getRandomWesternImage();
    $("#western").attr("src", image);
    console.log(image);

    for (var i = 0; i < western.length; i++) {
      // create the image element
      var imageElement = document.createElement('img');
      imageElement.setAttribute('src', western[i]);
    }

    imageTimer = setTimeout(updateImage, 5000);
}

onload = () => { imageTimer = setTimeout(updateImage, 5000); };
```

```css
.img2 {
  max-width: 110px;
  margin-bottom: 0.1px;
}
```

```html
<span id="western-wrapper">
       <img id="western" class="img2" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logos-brands-in-colors/436/Google_Pay_GPay_Logo-512.png" />
</span>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
```

If, for some reason, you want to stop the carousel, call `clearTimeout(imageTimer)`. Otherwise, you do not need to declare and save to `imageTimer`.

Also, for linear image swapping, try this:

```js
let western = ["https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logos-brands-in-colors/436/Google_Pay_GPay_Logo-512.png", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Apple_Pay_logo.svg/2560px-Apple_Pay_logo.svg.png", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/40/Klarna_Payment_Badge.svg/2560px-Klarna_Payment_Badge.svg.png"];

let imageTimer, imageIndex = 1; // Start at 1 so first update is second image.

function updateImage() {
    var image = western[imageIndex];
    $("#western").attr("src", image);
    console.log(image);
    imageIndex++;
    imageIndex *= (imageIndex < western.length);
    // The above line sets imageIndex back to 0 if we reached the end

    for (var i = 0; i < western.length; i++) {
      // create the image element
      var imageElement = document.createElement('img');
      imageElement.setAttribute('src', western[i]);
    }

    imageTimer = setTimeout(updateImage, 5000);
}

onload = () => { imageTimer = setTimeout(updateImage, 5000); };
```

```css
.img2 {
  max-width: 110px;
  margin-bottom: 0.1px;
}
```

```html
<span id="western-wrapper">
       <img id="western" class="img2" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logos-brands-in-colors/436/Google_Pay_GPay_Logo-512.png" />
</span>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: perf, thanks so much! One question tho, what if I don't want the order to be random, then what should I change here. As rn, the order is random, not consecutive to the list. @MJTech

Answer (score 2):

`setInterval` : method calls a function at specified intervals.

```js
const imgLinks = ["img-url1", "img-url2", "img-url3", "img-url4"];

        let pointer = 0;
        const img = document.querySelector("#img");
        const imgLen = imgLinks.length - 1;

        //for the first time preview on page load; it can also be set in <img src='img-url'>
        img.src = imgLinks[pointer];

        setInterval(() => {
            //if-condition is only useful if we need infinite-time preview (like image would start from 0 if reached last)
            if (pointer > imgLen) pointer = 0;
            img.src = imgLinks[pointer++];
        }, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <img id="img" src="">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a carousel, you could create a plugin that takes: the target element, the images array, and an update interval in ms.

```js
const paymentImages = [
  "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logos-brands-in-colors/436/Google_Pay_GPay_Logo-512.png",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Apple_Pay_logo.svg/2560px-Apple_Pay_logo.svg.png",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/40/Klarna_Payment_Badge.svg/2560px-Klarna_Payment_Badge.svg.png"
];

const carousel = new Carousel($('#western'), paymentImages, 2000).start();

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Stopping...');
  carousel.stop();
}, 9000);

function Carousel($el, images, updateMs) {
  this.$el = $el;
  this.images = images;
  this.updateMs = updateMs;
  this.imageTimer = null;
  this.imageIndex = -1;
  this.isRunning = false;

  this.updateImage = function() {
    if (!this.isRunning) return;
    this.imageIndex = (this.imageIndex + 1) % this.images.length;
    this.$el.attr('src', this.images[this.imageIndex]);
    this.imageTimer = setTimeout(boundedUpdateImage, updateMs);
  };

  const boundedUpdateImage = this.updateImage.bind(this);

  this.start = function() {
    this.isRunning = true;
    this.updateImage();
    return this;
  };
  
  this.stop = function() {
    clearTimeout(this.imageTimer);
  
    this.isRunning = false;
    this.imageTimer = null;
    this.imageIndex = -1;
  };

  return this;
}
```

```css
#western {
  max-width: 110px;
  margin-bottom: 0.1px;
}
```

```html
<span id="western-wrapper">
  <img id="western" />
</span>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.11.4/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
```